# How to order groups when using HSD.test() from the Agricolae package?

Tags: r, posthoc, tukey

my question about displaying the homogeneous subsets after a Tukey HSD test is already been asked in the past (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31547/how-to-obtain-the-results-of-a-tukey-hsd-post-hoc-test-in-a-table-showing-groupe, at the very end of the discussion) but never been answered. I'm running in the same problem now and I desperately need a solution as this function seems to be the only function available for R that displays such groups. If otherwise, please tell me. 
In short, this is what i get:

`Groups, Treatments and means
a        140095-001      36.79 
b        150004-001      32.1 
b        136936-021      31.97 
bc       137219-004      31.39 
bc       136673-017      31.27 
bc       136963-009      30.79 
bcd      147328-016      30.63 
bcd      0147592-01      30.55 
bcde     140094-001      30.02 
cde      136730-007      29.7 
de       136963-066      29.49 
ef       136936-004      28.4 
efg      147414-004      28.2 
efg      137109-036      28.2 
efg      136765-001      28.06 
efg      140089-001      27.82 
efg      137186-020      27.8 
fg       136936-006      27.48 
fgh      147350-014      27.43 
gh       136992-001      27.36 
gh       136730-015      27.18 
ghi      0147785-01      27.08 
ghi      0147691-01      26.98 
ghi      136891-010      26.7 
ghij     0147792-01      26.49 
ghijk    136947-014      26.3 
ghijkl   140097-001      25.8`

And this is what I want:

```
    Groups, Treatments and means
a        2.1     51.17547 
ab       4.1     50.7529 
abc      3.1     47.36229 
 bcd     1.1     45.81229 
  cd     5.1     44.55313 
   de    4.0     41.81757 
    ef   2.0     38.79482 
    ef   1.0     36.91257 
     f   3.0     36.34383 
     f   5.0     35.69507
```

I already checked the script behind the function but since my knowledge is rather low i couldn't find anything, at least nothing straight and clear. Could anybody help me with a solution? I would be very pleased with an answer.

Thanks in advance,
Jelle

Answer (score 0):

First build e.g. anova model by `aov` function

```
my_model <- stats::aov(data$value ~ data$treatment) 
summary(my_model)
```

Post hoc test with Tukey HSD, use anova model as input data, column `treatment` in original dataset is grouping factor.

```
test_result <- agricolae::HSD.test(my_model, "my_model$treatment", group = TRUE, console = TRUE)
```

And check the results in the console. There is, among others, also table with your asked overview. (not significant in my example)

```
  Groups, Treatments and means
 a   2008    6.755 
 a   2013    6.147 
 a   1975    4.653 
 a   1997    3.622
```

It is possible to visualize results for treatments.

```
agricolae::bar.group(test_result$groups, ylim = c(0,10), density = 10, border = "blue")
```

[image: Visualization for Tukey HSD]